# How to get Instagram usernames from a specific hashtag

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

*maybe I'm searching the wrong thing, but I can't find info.

Is there a way to get a list of all users that have posted on Instagram using a specific hashtag.

Or does anyone have a suggestion on a good way to randomly select a user that has posted using a specific tag?

Thanks!

*I have searched all over and can't seem to find any info about getting usernames from hashtags

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `tags/{tag}/media/recent` API endpoint to get media with hashtag, each media object will have the user info.

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{tag-name}/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

each API call will return 20 media, you have loop thru and find the user info, eliminate duplicates and save in an array, get the next set of 20 media using `pagination.next_url` in the API response and so on...

check out http://gramfeed.com/instagram/tags/sunrise, you can see photos and the user who posted